# Format date with moment vuejs

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

I hope you can help me, I need to show this format "2021-01-02" (YYY-MM-DD). but only show me 1 digit in month and day.

I have this in my app.js

```
var moment = require('moment');

getNow: function() {
          const today = new Date();
          const date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
          const date2 = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+(today.getDate()-1);
          const dateTime = date;
          const dateTime2 = date2;
          this.hoy = dateTime;
          this.ayer = dateTime2;
```

And I have this in my blade

```
hoy @{{hoy}} - ayer @{{ayer}}
```

show me this in my output:

hoy 2021-1-2 - ayer 2021-1-1

but I need to the format be "2021-01-02" because I need 2 digits for compare months and days

PD: Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using moment you can try:

```
const today = new Date();
this.hoy = moment(today).format('YYYY-M-D')
```